# How to make slurm make a scheduling decision when jobs are submitted?

Tags: slurm

I'm using back-fill scheduler with Slurm to manage a small GPU cluster. The backfill scheduler makes a scheduling decision every `bf_interval` seconds (default value is 30 seconds). This means even when GPU resources are available sometimes I have to wait for a while until the they are allocated. I can obviously reduce `bf_interval` but given that we don't have a lot of job submissions it'd be good if I could force slurm to run the scheduling routine the moment a job is queued. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

By default Slurm does it. From the [documentation](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sched_config.html):

> Slurm is designed to perform a quick and simple scheduling attempt at events such as job submission or completion and configuration changes.

Have you change the default configuration for this? And, are you sure that not scheduling on submission is your problem?

Comment: I don't think I have changed any of the scheduling settings. The only strange-looking option I can see is `FastSchedule=1` which apparently is not used anymore.
I'm pretty sure it's the scheduling because I can see that the resources are free but I have to wait up to 30 seconds until I'm allocated the resources.

Comment: With only your guess and without more information (logs, examples...) it will be difficult to help.